# PHP Search for string in file and print lines above/below match line

Tags: php

Question:

I am trying to search for a string in a file and print only the first line above and second line below the match line for all occurrences of the string. Is there a way I can achieve this with a PHP script? (will be updating a web page with output) couldn't find a solution other than via shell grep/awk which I can't use.

File content:

```
"timeUpdated":1533998971008
"name":"ABC"
"uptime":5143980267
"desiredStatus":"STARTED"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
"started":true
"serverArtifacts":[{"id":73
"timeUpdated":1525213888405
"name":"XYZ"
"uptime":6746828144F
"desiredStatus":"STARTED"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
"started":true 
"serverArtifacts":[{"id":21 
"timeUpdated":1544131291380
 "name":"KLM"
"uptime":6746828643
"desiredStatus":"STARTED"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
"started":true "serverArtifacts":[{"id":303
search for string: uptime -> print first line above (name:) and second line blow (lastReportedStatus:)
note: I can only use "uptime" as a search string since all other value pairs occur multiple times in a different sequence on other parts of the file.
expected output:
"name":"ABC"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
"name":"XYZ"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
"name":"KLM"
"lastReportedStatus":"STARTED"
```

Comment: That file content _almost_ looks like JSON

Comment: Yes PHP could do this. What code have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you read the lines in the file into an array:

```
$lines = file('file.txt', FILE_IGNORE_NEW_LINES);
```

Then you can just keep track of the key as you iterate the array, and find the lines relative to the line with "uptime" using simple addition/subtraction on the key.

```
foreach ($lines as $key => $line) {
    if (substr(trim($line),0, 8) == '"uptime"') {
        $result[] = $lines[$key - 1];
        $result[] = $lines[$key + 2] ?? '';
    }
}
```

You may need to add the `FILE_SKIP_EMPTY_LINES` option to `file()` if there really are blank lines between each line your file. I wasn't sure if it was just like that in the question here.

I'm curious where the file data comes from, though. It's very close to JSON, and if there was any way to get it the rest of the way there at the source, we wouldn't have to deal with it in such a hacky way here. This code will work for the example you showed, but it's not ideal.